# Xcode compiles data from Cocoapods, which was deleted

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am having strange problem with my iOS app. Project folder uses 85Mb and the app compiled from that project uses 138Mb on iPhone. This happened after I used [Skobblers](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios) SDK pod, however at the moment I have removed it - by removing 'pod Skobbler' from podfile. It seems that's not enough to remove pod, when app is being installed on iPhone in Xcode I can see that Skobblers files are being transfer to the phone (such as .mp3, .png for providing navigation).

My question is how to completely remove pod from Xcode project?

Comment: I am assuming you cleaned your target!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not agree with the other answer.

In Xcode, clean build folder:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>

Open a console:

```
cd <project name>
pod update
```

I think this is quite enough!

Comment: Yes, is the way to do a deep-clean of the project. You're welcome!